# how to open print preview window? c# from config file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to configure the preview window to open when printing, I tried putting *Microsoft Print to PDF* in the configuration file but it gives me an error.

[fileConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jx15.png)

"the settings to access the printer are invalid"

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWbmJ.png)

When I program a payment I have the printing check
[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYTRi.png)

the following code is executed
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78TlP.png)

```
 if (goPrint.Checked)
            {
                try
                {
                    printDocument.Print();
                    printDocument.Print();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al procesar la impresión:\n" + ex.Message,
                                    "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih13S.png)

```
// 
        // printDialog
        // 
        this.printDialog.Document = this.printDocument;
        this.printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;
        // 
        // printDocument
        // 
        this.printDocument.DocumentName = "Programación de pago";
        this.printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(this.printDocument_PrintPage);
```

how could i get the print preview window to open? thanks dtb

Comment: Show the code that uses the PolicyPrinter setting.

Comment: And now as text and not as a picture.

Comment: @Ralf I already put it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using PrintPreviewDialog, added it in my winform
[winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8FnK.png)

In the properties of printPreviewDialog, in Document I linked it with the function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3RNT.png)

and in the code I put the following

```
 if (goPrint.Checked)
        {
            try
            {
                printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //esto fue lo que agregue
                
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al procesar la impresión:\n" + ex.Message,
                                "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

In this way I was able to visualize the information before sending it to print

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2x5.png)